# Attach xlsx to email with MIME::Lite

Tags: excel, perl, mime-types

I am trying to send a email with an attached xlsx file using [`Excel::Writer::XLSX`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel%3a%3aWriter%3a%3aXLSX) and [`MIME::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME%3a%3aLite). The generation of the excel file works, as i can scp and open the file in Excel without any problems. When i try to open the attachment from my email client (Outlook 2013) i get this error:

> "Excel cannot open the file "from_2014-06_to_2014-07.xlsx" because the
>   file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has
>   not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of
>   the file."

The file size that outlook displays is 444B but its actually 95K. I have been sending xls files using [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel) and mime type "application/vnd.ms-excel" without any problems before.

Here is what I have tried to send the email:

```
sub send_mail{
    my $filename = shift;
    my $to_email = shift;
    my $from_email = shift;
    my $date = shift;
    $filename = shift;

    my $mail = MIME::Lite->new(
        'From'          => '$from_email',
        'To'            => $to_email,
        'Subject'       => "Radio/TV stats $date",
        'Type'          => 'multipart/mixed',
        #'content-type'  => 'application/zip',
        #'Data'       => "Here is your stuff",
    );

    $mail->attach(
        'Type'          => 'TEXT',
        'Data'          => "Here is your stuff",
    );

    $mail->attach(
        #'Type'          => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'Type'          => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        'Path'          => $filepath,
        'Filename'      => $filename,
        'Disposition'   => 'attachement',
    );

    $mail->send('sendmail');
}
```

Can anyone please help my attach the xlsx file?

Comment: Try `'Data' => "File size:". -s $filepath`

Comment: 'Data' => "File size". -s $filepath returns 0. ls -la returns 97403. Also the attachment still does not work.

Comment: So $filepath is wrong either if it is absolute or relative path. Also `use strict;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `shift` twice to `$filename` (2nd and 6th strings) and variable `$filepath` is not declared. May be here error?

Comment: AHhh... Must be to early in the morning. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Is it not possible to use absolute path in "Path => $filepath"

Comment: When attaching the xlsx file i also had to close the excel::writer first. If i didnt close it the absolute path did not work.